# Install a font from memory C++

Tags: c++, windows, fonts

I am working on a project and making font files encrypted due to privacy issues, and want to install it via the C++ application. But the issue is I can only install it when I decrypt it and place it physically on disk (AddFontResource). And this way the decrypted font file will be shown to the user which I don't want. Is there any way to read font as stream? Or any other better option?

Comment: Check the [AddFontMemResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontmemresourceex)

Comment: @Alex It will be private to our application, I want it to install for all applications and when I close my application, it must be delete.

Comment: @HafizMubashirTouqeer If you want the font to be accessible to other programs, it must be saved as a file and installed as such. You will just have to uninstall and delete the file when you are done using it. There is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, a better approach is not to call GDI AddFontResource, but rather to use DirectWrite and create a private font set. There is a code sample that covers exactly your scenario at https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DirectWriteCustomFontSets.

Answer (score 0):

> the issue is I can only install it when I decrypt it and place it physically on disk (AddFontResource).

That is only way to make the font accessible to other processes.  Using `AddFontMemResourceEx()` instead, you can install a font from the decrypted memory rather than from a disk file, but the font will only be accessible to the calling process, not to other processes.

> And this way the decrypted font file will be shown to the user which I don't want.

Sorry, but that is the only way if you want to make the font accessible to other processes.

> Is there any way to read font as stream?

There is no such option, no.